# How to double encrypt in Java using cipher?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

First time using cipher. I have two keys, k1 and k2, and a plaintext. I want to encrypt the plaintext and decrypt the enciphered text using k1 and k2.
Below is my work so far:

```
            // encryption part
            Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k1);
            byte[] firstEncryption = c1.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
            c2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k2);
            byte[] secondEncryption = c2.doFinal(firstEncryption);
            System.out.println("C(M) = " + secondEncryption);
```

```
            // decryption part
            Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
            c1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k2);
            byte[] firstDecryption = c1.doFinal(secret);
            Cipher c2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            c2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k1);
            byte[] secondDecryption = c2.doFinal(firstDecryption);
            System.out.println("Original text: " + new String(secondDecryption));
```

Then, when I try to run it, on the second round of encryption, I got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
```

I think this has something to do with the padding, but I did not find anything wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The amount of data that can get encrypted with RSA algorithm is limited and depends on the key length of the used RSA key. Try to use a longer RSA-ke (e.g. a 2.048 bit key).

Comment: Michael, I tried your suggestion and double the length, but it turned out to be another exception like "data must not be longer than 200-ish bytes".

Comment: How long is your plaintext? Asymmetric encryption like RSA or EC is very limited so you should consider a "Hybrid Encryption" scheme.

Comment: If you want to encrypt data two times using RSA, the one key must be larger than the other because the encrypted data has always the size of the key and RSA can only encrypt data that is smaller than the key: Data size -> key size 1 -> key size 2

Comment: Michael, my plaintext is just a line of words less than 20 characters, so I really dont think that's going to be a concern here.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, RSA is intended to encrypt only small piece of data (e. g. a symmetric key)

```
Data must not be longer than 117 bytes
```

So if you encrypt the data with the first key, the resulting ciphertext will have lenght of the modulo, which is longer than allowed 117 bytes and that prevents you executing the second round.

What is reason to use double encryption? To lock data with two separate keys? Then there are different ways to do that.

Example with two keys:

- generate 2 random symmetric keys (any number of keys) and the resulting data encryption key is combination (xor) of the individual keys
- encrypt data using the data encryption key (using a symmetric cipher, such as AES,...)
- encrypt individual key parts with different RSA keys